# Gulp Watch is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, compass-sass, gulp

I'm new Gulp user, and I try simple script to watch compass, but it didn't work. But when I just run `gulp compass` gulp can compile it. Any ideas? Here my script:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    compass = require('gulp-compass'),

// Compass
gulp.task('compass', function() {
    gulp.src('./assets/scss/*.scss')
        .pipe(compass({
            config_file: './config.rb',
            css: './assets/css',
            sass: './assets/scss'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/css'));
});

// Default task
gulp.task('default', function() {
    gulp.start('compass');
});

// Watch
gulp.task('watch', function() {

    // Watch .scss files
    gulp.watch('./assets/scss/*.scss', ['compass']);

});
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You've neglected to actually call the "watch" task, which is not the same thing as gulp.watch.  Your default gulp task should instead look like:

```
gulp.task('default', function() {
    gulp.start('compass');
    gulp.start('watch');
});
```

but it should really just look like:

```
gulp.task('default', ['compass', 'watch']);
```

Comment: How do you know that? He could be calling `gulp watch` from the command line.

Answer (score 9):

I changed `gulp.watch` source to `./assets/**/*.scss`

Comment: even though your own answer worked for you, please consider to use @cozuya answer as it is a good example to use Gulp.

Comment: Thank you @nizamil, this really helped me. Not sure why it didn't pick up on ./*.coffee, but when I changed it to ./**/*.coffee it worked. I think you should move the correct answer to this one.

Answer (score 5):

**IN GULP 4.X**

You have to pass a function. The customary way of doing this in gulp 4.x is to pass a `gulp.series()` invocation with only one task name. This returns a function that only executes the specified task.

```js
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('./assets/scss/*.scss', gulp.series('compass'))
});
```