# Using Gulp to Minify and Auto Update a CSS File

Tags: javascript, css, gulp, gulp-watch

I have a Gulp task that minifies my CSS in one folder and then pipes it to another folder.

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const cleanCSS = require("gulp-clean-css");

gulp.task("minify-css", () => {
  return (
    gulp
      .src("./css/**/*.css")
      .pipe(cleanCSS())
      .pipe(gulp.dest("minified"))
  );
});
```

The command `gulp minify-css` works perfectly.  I don't want to have to continually type that command in the terminal tho.

I want the code below to watch my CSS file and when it changes I want the `minify-css` task to run and update my minified file but it doesn't work:

```
gulp.task("default", function(evt) {
  gulp.watch("./css/**/*.css", function(evt) {
    gulp.task("minify-css");
  });
});
```

Any ideas on why this doesn't work?  Thank you in advance!

Comment: Maybe check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22831490/gulp-watch-is-not-working

Comment: I followed a suggestion and changed my `"default"` task to `"watch"` and then added `gulp.task('default', ['minify-css', 'watch']);` but when I run `gulp default` I get an error saying "Task function must be specified"

Comment: Looks like a version issue with gulp. Can you try using `gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('minify-css', watch'));` instead. Read more here: https://fettblog.eu/gulp-4-parallel-and-series/

Comment: This seemed to work the first time I ran the command.  It minifies the file and I get the return of `[19:50:48] Using gulpfile E:\GitHub\freeCodeCamp-Projects\personal-portfolio\gulpfile.js
[19:50:48] Starting 'default'...
[19:50:48] Starting 'minify-css'...
[19:50:48] Starting 'watch'...
[19:50:48] Finished 'minify-css' after 300 ms
[19:51:05] Starting '<anonymous>'...`

But then if I change something again and save the file it does not update my minified file

Comment: Anyone have any ideas to help me out?  I haven't been able to get it fixed unfortunately.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you create a minimal project and share your code here? It's hard to debug the issue without any reproducible code. Thanks.

Comment: Here is a codepen with all of the code https://codepen.io/JS-goose/pen/wQpLoq

My file structure is as follows:

Comment: Here is the file structure https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JS-goose/Projects/master/file-structure.png

Comment: Thanks for the files Jonathan. I've found the issue and provided a fix below. Please accept the answer if it works for you. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the area where you are calling `gulp.task('minify-css')` inside the `gulp.watch` callback function. That code does not actually invoke the minify-css task, but rather spawns an `anonymous` task as pointed by you in your logs. Instead `gulp.watch` should invoke a function which internally performs the `minify-css` job.

The other issue is probably the syntax changes that happened in gulp-4. They are not many but can be confusing.

I've managed to fix the issue and it works. Here is the updated code for `gulpfile.js` below:

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const cleanCSS = require("gulp-clean-css");

function minifyCSS() {
  return (
    gulp
      .src("./css/*.css")
      .pipe(cleanCSS())
      .pipe(gulp.dest("minified"))
  );
}

gulp.task("minify-css", minifyCSS);

gulp.task("watch", () => {
  gulp.watch("./css/*.css", minifyCSS);
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('minify-css', 'watch'));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This worked perfectly!  Thank you so very much for all of your help!  I added your solution to my `gulpfile.js` and it worked perfectly.  The minify process works every time I update my normal CSS file the minify runs correctly!  

Again, much thanks!