# Gulp to watch a css and minify on change

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-watch

I have the following gulp file which will watch my styles.scss file and update my style.css file. Each time the styles.css file updates i then need to run 'gulp minifycss' to minify it. Im wondering if there is a way to 'watch' the styles.css file and minify it automatically?

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
const minifyCSS = require('gulp-minify-css');
const minify = require('gulp-minify');

 // complie scss into css
function style() {
// where is my scss file
return gulp.src('./css/scss/**/*.scss')
// pass that file through scss compiler
    .pipe(sass())
//where do i save the compiled css?
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'))

// stream changes to all browsers
.pipe(browserSync.stream());
 }

function minifycss() {

return gulp.src('./css/styles.css')
.pipe(minifyCSS())
.pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
}

function watch () {
browserSync.init({      
    
 });
gulp.watch('./css/scss/**/*.scss', style);
gulp.watch('./css/styles.css', minifycss);
 }

exports.style = style;
exports.minifycss = minifycss;


exports.watch = watch;
```

I saw this post [Using Gulp to Minify and Auto Update a CSS File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53366997/using-gulp-to-minify-and-auto-update-a-css-file) and edited my gulp file to this:

```
function minifycss() {

return gulp.src('./css/styles.css')
.pipe(minifyCSS())
.pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
}

gulp.task("minify-css", minifyCSS);
gulp.task("watch",  () => {
  gulp.watch("./css/*.css", minifyCSS);
});
gulp.task('default', gulp.series('minify-css', 'watch'));
```

However, when i run it i get the following error:

**Did you forget to signal async completion?**

This is my Gulp details:

**CLI version: 2.3.0**
**Local version: 4.0.2**

Any ideas how i get this to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Gulp 4+ the tasks default to async, and therefore need to be signaled as finished. You can return the task to concatenate with others or if they are independent, just signal that the task has finished getting a callback method as a parameter in the task function (below I've named it `done`, but you can use any name you want).

Apart from that, to run tasks with `watch` you need to use `gulp.series()` to specify the task. Apart from that, since `watch` doesn't return immediately, you should use the end-signalling method that `watch` and `series` take as parameter too.

So, in your case, the code would be (I've not tested it, but it should work):

```js
gulp.task("minify-css", (done) => {
    gulp.src('./css/styles.css')
    .pipe(minifyCSS())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
    done();
});
gulp.task("watch",  (done) => {
  gulp.watch("./css/*.css", gulp.series(minifyCSS))(done);
});
gulp.task('default', (done) => gulp.series('minify-css', 'watch')(done));
```

Let me know if it works for you.